# How to control the ordering of operations in my MBean when viewed in JConsole or Java VisualVM

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, operations

I see this question was posted under title "jconsole operation ordering", but didn't see any responses to it and couldn't add a comment as I am new. So posting this question again!

I have an MBean with many operations and would want to present them in a certain order in JConsole or Java VisualVM. Couldn't find a way to do so. Was wondering if it's even possible to control the presentation ordering of operations in a MBean?

Comment: Found a solution on a different blog thought I will share it here as well. Check out [adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper](http://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/) Also See [JMXWrapper](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JMXWrapper) for a description on how to do this.